# Point 1and1 domain to my vps

Tags: dns, vps

I would like to point my 1and1 domain to a vps which I am going to buy(https://portal.obtrix.net/cart.php?a=confproduct&i=3). But, the vps registration page requires hostname, ns1, ns2. how? to point my 1and1 domain to this vps. I need the hostname, ns1, ns2 at registration.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that when you purchase a VPS, you must name your own prefix for your hostname and nameservers. In other words, you will not find these prefixes anywhere else. Instead, you must create your own. You can follow the conventions like:

1. `server1.[yourdomainname].com` or `s1.[yourdomainname].com` for your hostname
2. `ns1.[yourdomainname].com` and `ns2.[yourdomainname].com` for your name servers

Once you have created your VPS, you should go back to the company you registered your domain with, go to your control panel where you can manage your domain, and then point your domain to your new VPS by entering in the hostname and name servers you designated for your new VPS.

Comment: must use "server1.[yourdomainname].com" or "s1.[yourdomainname].com" for my hostname? Thanks

Comment: No, I believe "server1.[yourdomainname].com" or "s1.[yourdomainname].com" are conventional ways of naming your prefix. My suggestion, try giving your own unique names for the prefixes and see if it works.  :)